# Issues on how to INDEX my database

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, indexing, database-optimization

Please i need your help with how to include  `INDEXES` in my tables, i've read about it in several tutorials but still cant implement it on my database . To increase the efficiency of my database: 
I have installed `php_apc.dll` on the wampserver and it's faster a bit,  I have also tried to avoid the use of  `SELECT *`
 in my queries where neccessary. But how to implement  `INDEX` is my problem. I'll be glad if you can please point out where it'll be nesseccary to `INDEX`.

Here is my database schema

```
  Database: RESULTS
  -------------------

   Table: STUDENTS
   - studentID (int)
   - first_name (varchar)
   - last_name (varchar)
   - other_name (varchar)

   Table: COURSES
   - courseID (int)
   - course_code (varchar)
   - course_title (varchar)
   - course_unit (int)

   Table: SEMESTER
   - semesterID
   - semester_name

   Table: MAINTABLE
   - scoresID (int)
   - courseID (int)
   - studentID (int)
   - semester_name (varchar)
   - session (varchar) 
   - score (int)
   - grade (varchar)
   - remarks (varchar)
```

Most of my queries revolve round
`INSERT` INTO `MAINTABLE` ,  `STUDENTS` .....  then  `SELECT` FROM `MAINTABLE` ,  `STUDENTS` and `COURSES`

Thank you for your patience and time. I most appreciate it.
Thanks.

**EXAMPLES OF QUERIES"

```
                   $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT       first_name, last_name
        FROM students 
      WHERE matric_no = '".$matric_no."' ");
    ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)); 

    $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT  SUM(c.        course_unit) AS 'TOTAL'
               FROM    maintable AS m  
           INNER JOIN students AS s ON
                m.matric_no = s.matric_no
          INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
             m.course_code = c.course_code
       WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
          AND m.level = '".$level."'") or 
 die (mysql_error());

             $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT  c.          course_unit, m.score 
         FROM    maintable AS m  
                 INNER JOIN students AS s ON
                      m.matric_no = s.matric_no
                  INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
           m.course_code = c.course_code
      WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
                      AND m.level = '".$level."'") 
      or die (mysql_error()); 

              $query5 = mysql_query("SELECT  c.         course_unit, m.score 
             FROM    maintable AS m  
         INNER JOIN students AS s ON
             m.matric_no = s.matric_no
                     INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
                 m.course_code = c.course_code
     WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'")           or die (mysql_error()); 


    $query6 = mysql_query("SELECT  SUM(c.              course_unit) AS 'TOTAL'
                     FROM    maintable AS m  
                      INNER JOIN students AS s ON
                              m.matric_no = s.matric_no
                      INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
                 m.course_code = c.course_code
      WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'")           or die (mysql_error());     



            $query7 = mysql_query("SELECT  m.                            course_code AS 'Course Code',        c.course_title AS 'Course Title'
 , c.course_unit AS 'Unit',
  m.score AS 'Score', m.grade AS 'Grade'
                      FROM    maintable AS m  
                      INNER JOIN students AS s ON
                m.matric_no = s.matric_no
                      INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
                 m.course_code = c.course_code
  WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
  AND m.level = '".$level."'") 
   or die (mysql_error());
               $number_cols = mysql_num_fields         ($query7);

            $query8 = mysql_query("SELECT  m.         score, m.course_code 
                      FROM    maintable AS m  
                      INNER JOIN students AS s ON
                              m.matric_no = s.matric_no
                      INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
                 m.course_code = c.course_code
         WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
      AND m.score >= 0 AND m.score < 40 ")         or die (mysql_error());

                   $query9 = mysql_query("SELECT          m.grade, m.course_code 
                      FROM    maintable AS m  
                      INNER JOIN students AS s ON
                              m.matric_no = s.matric_no
                      INNER JOIN courses AS c ON
               m.course_code = c.course_code
         WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
                      AND m.grade = 'AR'") 
    or die (mysql_error());
```

Please forgive  my formating. I typed from a mobile. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Impossible to help w/o seeing the queries you're doing

Comment: Blind advice: Index anything that shows up a WHERE clause.  Better advice: Index things that will have a large set of possibilities when filtering.

Comment: More blind advice, index EVERYTHING that is used in a join

Comment: Also order by, group by used columns

Comment: Let's just go ahead and generalize:  Index anything that involves filtering or grouping.  :)

Comment: This is just missing so much...What is going on with the semester table - nothing references it? Why does maintable not have a primary key? Why would there be a scoresid, and then a score field right below it. Are your queries slow? How slow? Did you benchmark?

Comment: @travisj ... I have given examples of the queries i'm running. Please give your advices accordingly. Thank you for your time and comments. I most appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should begin by running all queries with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html). That should show you some pointers.

But if you are asking for a rule of thumb, this would be the general guideline:

- index columns which are `FOREIGN KEY` in `JOIN` statements
- index all the columns used in `WHERE` conditions
- index all the columns used in `ORDER BY`

Also there seem to be a lot of VARCHAR searches. Some additional [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) might give beneficial results too. It is easier to search for `level_id` then for `level` name.

Also, as a side note: please stop using the ancient `mysql_*` function. They are 10+ years old, no longer maintained and the process of making them deprecated [had already begun](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should start using [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). One should't write new code with `mysql_*` API.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit too general to be well answered here, but my guidance to you is to focus on your WHERE clauses - if you use something a lot in WHERE then put an index on it and it will make those queries faster. Also, if you do any joins, put indexes on what you use in your ON clauses. That's so over-generalizing that I expect to be pounced upon for saying it, but general questions beget general answers.

More specificity would be your showing your table structures and actually showing a query or two. But then it gets preciously close to our doing your work for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I have updated with examples of the queries i'm running. Please advice accordingly. Thanks

Comment: I like the "if you do any joins".

Answer (score 0):

Another general answer is, if you search for something in columns which contains string data like students' first name or last name, I'd suggest you put an index on those columns.

This would increase speed of retrieving results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please check my updated question and please give your advice.

Comment: As in D Mac's answer, follow your joins and try to put indexes on columns you use on each side of "ON" statements.

Also, check your where statement.

Comment: Some of the columns to put Indexes on would be "level","matric_no","course_code" and "score". I hope you get the basic idea.